# How to traverse a list of string items and insert another string item(s) based on certain conditions?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Lets say I have a list of String items in a list like:
"Apple",
"Apricot",
"Banana",
"Blueberry",
"Fig",
"Grape"...

As you see We have a few A items, few B items, then we skip C D and E before picking back up with an F and a G item. I need help figuring out how to traverse this list and Insert an "A" before the A items, then a "B" before the B items, and so on...but the important part is even though there are no C, D, or E items I still need there to be a "C", "D", and "E" inserted? So when printed out to the screen it would look something like this...

- "A"
- "Apple"
- "Apricot"
- "B"
- "Banana"
- "Blueberry"
- "C"
- "D"
- "E"
- "F"
- "Fig"
- "G"
- "Grape"

Is there a way to do this with vanilla C#?

Comment: What have you tried? What _specifically_ is not working?

Comment: The slow way is just to insert A to G to the end, and then sort the list, but I'm guessing you are not happy with that?

Comment: *"how to traverse this list and..."* - well, start by traversing the list. Can you do that?

Comment: Well, what you want is not traverse the list but sort the list. Google for sorting algorithms. Edit: And `List` has a `Sort` method

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this:

```
string letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
List<string> listOfWords = new List<string>
{
    "Appricot",
    "Apple",
    ...
};

foreach (string letter in letters)
{
    Console.WriteLine(letter);
    List<string> words = listOfWords.Where(word => word[0].ToUpper().Eqauls(letter)).ToList();
    words.ForEach(word => Console.WriteLine(word));
}
```

This would loop through all the letters in `letters` and print them to the console.

Then it would get all the words in `listOfWords` where they begin with the letter and print them out.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: You end up traversing `listOfWords` way more than you need to this way though.  Meaning its not very efficient

Comment: @maccettura do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this can be done in tonne of other better ways but simplest one is-

```
List<string> prods = new List<string>();

            prods.AddRange(new List<string>() {
                "Apple",
                "Apricot",
                "Banana",
                "Blueberry",
                "Fig",
                "Grape"
            });

            //Considering that the list is already sorted alphabetically
            //or you can use prods.Sort();
            List<string> newList = new List<string>();

             string alphabets = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            foreach(char a in alphabets)
            {
                newList.Add(a.ToString());
                foreach (var item in prods)
                {
                    if (item.StartsWith(a.ToString()) || item.StartsWith(a.ToString().ToUpper()))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"adding {item} to  newlist");
                        newList.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (var item in newList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }


            Console.ReadKey();
```

Please let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: Why go through the extra effort of splitting the alphabet by commas?

Comment: Yes not required updated the same. Thanks for noting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems really easy.

```cs
var yourList = new List<string>() { 
    "Apple", "Apricot", "Banana", "Blueberry", "Fig", "Grape"
};

yourList
  .AddRange("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList());

yourList.Sort();
```